# CDI beans aren't working, but managed beans are

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, cdi, managed-bean

I'm trying to populate a PrimeFaces data table:

```
<p:dataTable var = "milestoneIndentifier" id="milestoneTable" value = "#{milestoneIdentifierManager.milestoneIdentifiers}" paginator="true" >
    <p:column sortBy="name" headerText = "Milestone">
        <h:outputText value ="#{milestoneIndentifier.name}" /> 
    </p:column>

    <p:column sortBy="acroynm" headerText = "Acroynm">
        <h:outputText value ="#{milestoneIndentifier.acronym}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column sortBy="phaseName" headerText = "Phase Name">
        <h:outputText value ="#{milestoneIndentifier.phaseName}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText = "Action">
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I'm using this backing bean:

```
//@ManagedBean
//@ViewScoped
@Named
@ViewAccessScoped
public class MilestoneIdentifierManager extends PageBean {    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<MilestoneIdentifier> milestoneIdentifiers; 
    @Inject
    private MilestoneIdentifierBusinessBean milestoneIdentifierBusiness;

    public MilestoneIdentifierManager() {
    }
    /**
     * @param name
     * @param acronym
     * @param phaseName
     */
    public void addMilestoneIdentifier(String name, String acronym, String phaseName)  {
        try {
            milestoneIdentifierBusiness.addMilestoneIdentifier(name, acronym, phaseName);
        } catch (AllValidationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }

    public List<MilestoneIdentifier> getMilestoneIdentifiers() {
        return milestoneIdentifiers;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        milestoneIdentifiers = new ArrayList<MilestoneIdentifier>();
        milestoneIdentifiers.add(new MilestoneIdentifier("Milestone A", "MSA", "Milestone A1"));
    }
}
```

When I try to do this, the table says that no records are found. If I comment out:

```
@Named
@ViewAccessScoped
```

and uncomment:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
```

then the table will show the milestone I created in the `init` method.

**Edit:** I have a `beans.xml` file in the WEB-INF folder.

Here are the code imports:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ViewAccessScoped;
```

Some of these are not used and I haven't cleaned up the code.

Comment: Can you show your import statements? Obviously don't need any of your internal code imports.

Comment: added them to the question.